# It takes nearly 10 seconds before audio from remote URL starts playing

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am able to play the sound from one URL. But takes nearly 10 seconds to play the audio.

```
@IBAction func playBtnTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = URL(string: muscUrl!)!
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.player!.play()
}
```

I am new to iOS. I am not sure, how can I download the URL audio and then play that audio? I don't want that 10 sec delay to play audio.

Update, I tried :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let urlstring = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tailtoddle_lo4.mp3"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
    print("the url = \(url!)")
    downloadFileFromURL(url: url!)
}

func downloadFileFromURL(url:NSURL){
    var downloadTask:URLSessionDownloadTask
    var request = URLRequest(url:url as URL)
    downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (URL, response, error) -> Void in
        self.play(url: URL as! NSURL)
    })

    downloadTask.resume()
}

func play(url:NSURL) {
    print("Playing \(url)")

    do {
        self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
        player!.prepareToPlay()
        player!.volume = 1.0
        player!.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        //self.player = nil
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } catch {
        print("AVAudioPlayer init failed")
    }
}
```

getting error in console :

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)

in line `self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)`

Comment: What is `url` when you print it?

Comment: my url is like this "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tailtoddle_lo4.mp3"

Comment: You cannot download an `http` URL. You should be getting an error warning of this.

Comment: I fed your URL into a web browser and I did not get any mp3 file.

Comment: sory please try this "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/Music1/v4/fd/4b/f9/fd4bf91e-2a1d-a946-a2f5-2d828da0f8e5/mzaf_2707169172634594413.plus.aac.p.m4a"

Comment: OK I tried it with your first code (just streaming the sound directly into an AVPlayer) and I couldn't get any 10-second delay. Note that your second code, downloading and then playing, would definitely be slower!

Comment: my first code button action is getting delay for 10 sec in my button action

Comment: are u not getting that ?

Comment: No, I'd say the delay is no longer than half a second. Do you have a very slow Internet connection? The buffer needs to fill up before the playback can start, so that would make it take longer. But what you're doing in that code is still right.

Comment: it takes time may be because you are download song from that link and then you start download...

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is correct. I don't experience any significant delay when I run it on my device. Naturally it can take some time on a slow Internet connection to fill the buffer before playback can start; but your second code, downloading and then playing, would therefore be even slower.

If you want to know what's happening with the AVPlayer's buffer, use KVO to track changes in its `timeControlStatus`.